# How to Generate both X509Data and KeyValue within KeyInfo Element with WSS4J

Tags: soap, cxf, saml, opensaml, wss4j

I need to generate the KeyInfo element of a SAML assertion that has both the X509Data element with the X509 certificate and the KeyValue element with the public key. It should look like this:

```
                        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                            <ds:X509Data>
                                <ds:X509Certificate>MIIGLTCquvS ... </ds:X509Certificate>
                            </ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:KeyValue>
                                <ds:RSAKeyValue>
                                    <ds:Modulus>vOksZtPkaxkdxN ..... </ds:Modulus>
                                    <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
                                </ds:RSAKeyValue>
                            </ds:KeyValue>
                        </ds:KeyInfo>
```

I'm using Wss4jOutInterceptor and CXF with a SAMLCallback to generate the Assertion. I can get it to generate either the X509Data or the KeyValue but not both. This has to be in both the SubjectConfirmationData as well as in the Signature of the Assertion. I've seen some answers where you do this using OpenSAML and building it all up by hand, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way using WSS4J.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom KeyInfo Element by setting a DOM Element on KeyInfoBean.setElement(). There is not currently a way to do the same though for Signature KeyInfos. I've fixed this in the current code-base:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WSS-619

Here is the commit including test:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1817084

It might take some effort wiring this through with CXF's WSS4JOutInterceptor though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the setElement on the KeyInfoBean for the Subject but either the X509 or the KeyValue get lost somewhere in the WSS4JOutInterceptor processing it seems.  I'm beginning to think it might just be simpler to go with "raw" Opensaml and a custom CXF interceptor at this point. Do you know of any good links or example of that approach? Thanks again for the help